# Conveying 'as ~ as I would have liked'

Tags: phrases

What's the best way to convey sentences like:

1. His arguments didn't seem as convincing as I would have liked
2. Last week, I couldn't study Japanese as much as I would have liked

The best I could muster up was 期待通り since both of these involve some form of expectation. But I'm not too sure if it sounds natural/makes sense.

Comment: I wonder if 思ったほど is as close as you would have liked to your desired phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 思ったほど, (私が)期待していたほど, 考えていたほど, etc.

> 彼の議論には、(こちらが)期待していたほど(は)説得力がないようだった。
> 彼の意見には私が思うほどの説得力はなさそうだった。
>
> His arguments didn't seem as convincing as I would have liked/expected.

If you want to use 期待通り, you have to be careful not to change the meaning:

> - 彼の議論には、期待通り説得力がないようだった。
>   (私が)思った通り、彼の意見には説得力がなさそうだった。
>   As I had expected, his arguments didn't seem convincing.
> - 彼の議論には、期待通り**の**説得力がないようだった。
>   彼の意見には(私が)思った通り**の**説得力がなさそうだった。
>   His arguments didn't seem to be as convincing as I expected.